# What does "may" mean?

Tags: meaning, auxiliary-verbs

> “Well, Voldemort’s going to try other ways of coming back, isn’t he? I
>   mean, he hasn’t gone, has he?”
>  “No, Harry, he has not. He is
>   still out there somewhere, perhaps looking for another body to share…
>   not being truly alive, he cannot be killed. He left Quirrell to die;
>   he shows just as little mercy to his followers as his enemies.
>   Nevertheless, Harry, while you **may** only have delayed his
>   return to power, it will merely take someone else who is prepared to
>   fight what seems a losing battle next time — and if he is delayed
>   again, and again, why, he **may** never return to power.”  (Harry
>   Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

The second *may* has the meaning of 2 below, while the first may seems to be 1. But it is within a while clause that has the meaning of although, it’s not clear for me. What does the first may mean?

#### [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/may)

1. used to say that something is possible
2. used when admitting that something is true before introducing another point, argument, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have it reversed.

The first use of *may* admits a counter-argument before introducing a main point. The second use expresses a possibility. **On the one hand**, Harry only delayed his return (not fully defeated him), on the other hand **it's possible** he'll never return to power.

Notice that in the 2nd definition, the word *may* is "used when admitting...". *May* by itself isn't enough to create this meaning, it's only used as part of the idiom. The *While* here is simply another part of the construction that admits one thing before introducing another.

> While you may not believe me, I still stand by my story.